# Default to map view when opening Google Map directions link on mobile web

Tags: google-maps, mobile, web, map-directions

Is there a query parameter I can use to default a mobile Google Maps directions link to the map view instead of the text view?

Open this link on mobile, or change browser user-agent to a mobile one: https://maps.google.com/maps?dirflg=w&saddr=51.52732134995272,-0.10802237782646251&daddr=7%20Clerkenwell%20Close,%20Clerkenwell,%20EC1R%200DY

The view defaults to the first image here, but i want it to default to the second one (you can manually toggle between the two views using the icon 2nd from the right in the nav bar):

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue, please share the solution.

Comment: you can find the solution here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/61953286/2420700](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61953286/2420700)