# Auto start navigation with React Native Google Maps Directions package

Tags: google-maps, react-native

I have a requirement that on loading the google map application, have to automatically start the navigation.

Current scenario - It shows the route but user has to click on `start` to start navigation
I couldn't find any flag associated for the same?

[Found this article which shows the flags used in google maps](http://alvarestech.com/temp/routeconverter/RouteConverter/navigation-formats/src/main/doc/googlemaps/Google_Map_Parameters.htm)

[Official google maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) shows to use it as `dir_action=navigate` but I am clueless on how to translate it into `react-native-google-maps-directions` package

Any idea how could we approach the problem?

Comment: The `react-native-maps-directions` component makes a request to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json ([source code](https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions/blob/master/src/MapViewDirections.js#L76)) whereas the `dir_action=navigate` parameter is associated with the map action request to https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&parameters. So they are different endpoints. Could you possibly put your code in a https://codesandbox.io/ project so we can explore other options? Have you tried triggering the start event somehow?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [react-native-maps-directions](https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions) uses the Directions API to display routes. Please note that Directions API doesn't include any real-time navigation, it is meant only to show routes. The real-time navigation additionally is prohibited in the Google Maps APIs.

Have a look at the Google Maps API Terms of Service paragraph 10.4 (c, iii). It reads

> **No navigation.** You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions

In order to be compliant with Google Maps API Terms of Service you should open the Google Maps app installed in your device using the [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) in navigation mode.

```
var url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate&destination=Los+Angeles";
Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
    if (!supported) {
        console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
    } else {
        return Linking.openURL(url);
    }
}).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Oh I didnt't know that. Nice to know, thanks! Although I haven't tried your bit of code, I just had a preliminary doubt, if you call this url via `Linking` component, will the intent open? Or will it directly navigate to the application. @xomena

Comment: @xomena, if I need draw route in real time, from user current location, do you know a solution for that in react-native ?
If I will send requests to google maps directions API I will use all limits in few hours. And I cant find something else.

Or it is not possible at all ?

Comment: @Kholiavko get coordinates and draw route using polyline

Comment: see this comment work 100% on React-native https://stackoverflow.com/a/61953286/2420700

Comment: hi, how can i add latitude and longitude values in this url? i have only latitude and longitude values. Any solution?

var url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate&destination=Los+Angeles";

Comment: @Harika According to documentation the origin and destination parameters `The value can be either a place name, address, or comma-separated latitude/longitude coordinates. `. So just add coma separated lat/lng in the url. Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action

Comment: @ xomena Thanks for your reply.
I tried this https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate&destination=lat,long
it's working fine.

Comment: for me value of supported is always false
though URL is valid it returns false.
but if I open it directly, it will open in google map
I want to check if google map is installed in iOS device
please help
@xomena

Answer (score 6):

> 100% work

If you want to auto-start navigation from your current location to specific location https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation

> Sample Code

```
static googleMapOpenUrl = ({ latitude, longitude }) => {
    const latLng = `${latitude},${longitude}`;
    return `google.navigation:q=${latLng}`;
  }
```

> To open google map on click React-Native will do like this

```
Linking.openURL(googleMapOpenUrl({ latitude: 23.235899, longitude: 78.323258 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    import getDirections from "react-native-google-maps-directions";
    ...

    handleGetDirections = () => {
        const data = {
            source: {
                latitude: originLatitude,
                longitude: originLongitude
            },
            destination: {
                latitude: destinaationLatitude,
                longitude: destinationLatitude
            },
            params: [
                {
                    key: "travelmode",
                    value: "driving"  // may be "walking", "bicycling" or "transit" as well
                },
                {
                    key: "dir_action",
                    value: "navigate" // this instantly initializes navigation using the given travel mode
                }
            ]
        }
        getDirections(data)
    }
```

**Source:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-maps-directions#install

Answer (score 0):

Add an intent to `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` (a new requirement since Android 11 SDK 30):

```xml
<intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="google.navigation" />
</intent>
```

Use `Linking.openURL` with a [universal, cross-platform URL to launch Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action) e.g. The following example launches a map with bicycling directions from the Space Needle to Pike Place Market, in Seattle, WA:

```
Linking.canOpenURL(url).then((supported) => {
    if (supported) {
      Linking.openURL(`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Space+Needle+Seattle+WA&destination=Pike+Place+Market+Seattle+WA&travelmode=bicycling`);
    } else {
      logger.error("Don't know how to open URI: " + url);
    }
  });
```

Sources

- Android intent - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65114851/3469524
- Linking.openURL - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804295/3469524
- [Universal, cross-platform URL to launch Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action)